# C++ Printing/cout overlaps in multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, printing, cout

I was wondering how I could handle printing when using multiple threads.
I thought it would be pretty simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

bool printing = false;

struct argumentStruct {
    int a;
    float b;
};

void *ThreadFunction(void *arguments) {
  struct argumentStruct*args = (struct argumentStruct*)arguments;
  int a = args->a;
  float b = args->b;
    while (printing) {}
    printing = true;
      cout << "Some text...." << a << b << endl;
    printing = false;
}

main() {
    pthread_t threads[3];
    struct argumentStruct argStruct[3];

    argStruct[0].a = 1;
    argStruct[0].b = 1.1;
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, &ThreadFunction, (void *)&argStruct[0]);

    argStruct[1].a = 2;
    argStruct[1].b = 2.2;
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, &ThreadFunction, (void *)&argStruct[1]);

    argStruct[2]a = 3;
    argStruct[2].b = 3.3;
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, &ThreadFunction, (void *)&argStruct[2]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't really work that well. Some couts are just skipped (or maybe overwritten?).
So what am I doing wrong? How can I handle this properly?

Comment: There's this thing called a *mutex* ...

Comment: `printing` would lack uniform visibility by all threads. You are advised to use proper concurrency mechanisms (mutex, lock, ...).

Comment: You could try `volatile bool printing` or use a `std::mutex`. Hard to know what else to suggest without your actual code.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for: even with a `std::mutex` all you are doing is ensuring that multiple writes don't occur **at the same time**.  output from different threads can still happen **in any order**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the statements that test and set the `printing` variable are not **atomic**, i.e., they don't execute without being interrupted by the OS scheduler which switches the CPU among threads. You should use [*mutexes*](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html) in order to stop other threads while printing. Here you have a nice example:

http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/70/basic-and-easy-pthread-mutex-lock-example-c-thread-synchronization

Comment: Thank you, the example from your link works great. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition, where two (or more) threads can both set `printing` to `true`.

This is because assignment is not an *atomic* operation, it's done in multiple steps by the CPU, and if the thread is interrupted before the actual setting of the variable to `true`, and another thread starts running, then you can have two threads running simultaneously both believing the variable is `true`. For more clarity:

1. Thread A sees that `printing` is `false`
2. Thread A is interrupted
3. Thread B starts running
4. Thread B sees that `printing` is `false`
5. Thread B sets `printing` to `true`
6. Thread B is interrupted
7. Thread A is scheduled and starts running again
8. Thread A sets `printing` to `true`

Now both thread A and B are running full speed ahead.

That's why there are threading primitives such as *semaphores* and *mutex* that handle these things.

Comment: Your answer analyses the problem but offers no solution (I do not count "_there are semaphors and mutexes_" as a solution).